# XCode 4.3.1 Installation

Tags: osx-lion, xcode4.3

I've recently installed XCode 4.3.1 which I downloaded from developer.apple.com site. Previously, I uninstalled an older version (XCode 4.1) by command line from /Developer/Applications... directory.

Now, I can't find any XCode directory at this point, neither I can't found XCode.app in /Applications folder.

Somebody knows where I can find XCode launcher, uninstaller or directory where I can run the app?

My OS: Mac OS X 10.7.3 (Lion)

Any help will be appreciated!

Regards.

Comment: I don't think this really is a Stack Overflow question. SuperUser, maybe?

Comment: As Jasper said, I moved this question to SuperUser (take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/414913/xcode-4-3-1-installation). It's more accurate place to ask this kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

If your running Lion you probably should be downloading xCode from the app store instead of developer.apple.com

Comment: Yeah, I know, but in the app store it is the latest version and they don't let me choose older versions. In this case I need 4.3.1 precisely. Thanks.